# Is it possible to multiply a set by a natural number?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Say I have a set $S=\{1, 4, 10, 7\}$. Could I then multiply $S$ by $3$? Would that then look like $3S=\{3, 12, 30, 21\}$? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Yes you could just *define* $$n\{a_i\}=\{na_i\}$$

Comment: You can certainly take a set of numbers $S= \{1,4,10,7\}$ and say "Hey, I'm going to multiply every element by $3$ and get the set $\{3,12,20,21\}$ and I'm going to call that set $3S$".  And you can say "I'm going to refer to that as multiplying a set by a number, any objections?  No? Good."

Comment: I'm not sure what is being asked here. You can most certainly do **anything** you want in maths (assuming logically valid). Are you asking about usefulness of this construction?

Comment: @fleablood I do have an objection since $3 \times 10 = 30$

Comment: Given an abstract set $X$. What is $3X$?
As it is phrased, it seems that OP has a subset of some sort of algebraic object in mind; of course, then its possible

Comment: Hello and welcome to Math Stack exchange. What is your background? Where did you come across this notation or problem? Especially for a problem like this context is very important.

Comment: though if you define $A+B$ to mean any element of $A$ plus any element of $B$ and $3A$ to mean $A+A+A$ then in your example you would have  $3S = \{3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30\}$

Comment: @Henry Again, that depends on what you decide to define. Just because $3x \equiv x + x + x$ for numbers doesn't mean you have to follow that convention with number/set operations. You might, for example, decide that $3\times S \equiv S + S + S$ and use $3S \equiv \{3x | x \in S\}$.

Comment: @kesa „what is 3X?“ – allow me to remark that to some people, $3X$ is just the $\underline{\operatorname{Set}}$-coproduct (a.k.a. “disjoint union”) of three instances of $X$.

Comment: @Luke that’s exactly my point.. Some people might view it as abstract sum in general, or whatever they like.. but that’s not what seems to be the concern of this question

Answer (score 24):

Sure, we sometimes for example denote the set of even integers by $2\Bbb Z=\{\dots,-4,-2,0,2,4,\dots\}$, while the set of integers is $\Bbb Z=\{\dots,-2,-1,0,1,2,\dots\}$.

Answer (score 8):

Yes..you have already defined the operation..a scalar multiplication on a set.

Answer (score 7):

In fact, this is closely related to images of functions:

> Let $f: A \to B$ be a function between two sets and $A' \subseteq A$, then we define
>   $$f[A'] := \{f(a)\ |\ a \in A'\}\quad \left(= \{b \in B\ |\ \exists a' \in A'. f(a') = b\}\right)$$

Your idea is a specific instance:

> Let $A' = \{1, 4, 10, 7\} \subseteq \mathbb{N} =: A$ and $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ be the operation "multiply by three", then
>   $$f[A'] = \{3, 12, 30, 21\}$$

[The other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3065823/85341) hints at the notation $NA'$, e.g. $3A'$.

Note that in general only $|A'| \geq |f[A']|$ holds, e.g. consider $0\mathbb{Z} = \{0\}$. However, with this "function framework", it is easy to state a criterion for when the equality holds:

> If $f$ is injective on $A'$, then $|A'| = |f[A']|$.

Or in words: "If you map different elements in $A'$ to different elements in $B$, then certainly, we cannot lose elements due to duplicates in the set $f[A']$."

Can you see why $|2\mathbb{Z}| = |\mathbb{Z}|$? This proves "there are as many even numbers as integers". (Of course, you have to first define the cardinality function $|\cdot|$ for arbitrary infinite sets first.)